# My SQL query is working very slow. Taking 3 second to check between 30 thousand rows

Tags: php, mysql, database, eloquent

I have a MySQL database where i have 3 tables in which each of the table will have nearly 30,000 records. Here is how my table structure looks like, **is there any problem in my table structure?**:

I have one table with name `leads` its structure is like this :

```
CREATE TABLE `rico16_leads` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mobilealt` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `investment` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `profileimage` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `callback` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `conversation` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `dob` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `pan_card` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `broking_from` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `lead_existence` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'exist',
  `assign_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `register_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `used_status` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unused',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25883 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Then i have another table with name `status` (here i am storing some services as well), looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE `rico16_status` (
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `status` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `plans` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `details` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `termscondition` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `showdropdown` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `invoicefilterdropdown` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `trash` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=80 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Now on the basis of these two tables i have another table name `leads_services`, it looks like the screenshot below. Here `lead_id`, `status_id` and `invoice_id` are foreign keys:

```
CREATE TABLE `rico16_lead_services` (
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `invoice_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
      `status_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
      `lead_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
      `service_startdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `service_enddate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `active` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `callby_call` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `callby_sms` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `callby_email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `review` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `trash` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31761 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I have one more table through which i am fetching the data that is `conversation` here i take record of all the conversation with individual leads. Here is how it looks like :

```
    CREATE TABLE `rico16_conversations` (
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `user_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
      `lead_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
      `conversation` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Now i am not sure if i am making any structure wise any mistake here. But my simple join queries are taking a long time to fetch the data. And i am sure data will be increased to millions of records, but with this small data as well, its going very slow, which is making me worried.

Here are few relations with each of these tables:

```
ALTER TABLE `rico16_leads`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `leads_mobile_unique` (`mobile`),
  ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`) USING BTREE;

ALTER TABLE `rico16_leads`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=25883;

ALTER TABLE `rico16_status`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `rico16_status`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=80;

ALTER TABLE `rico16_lead_services`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `rico16_lead_services`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=31761;

ALTER TABLE `rico16_conversations`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

ALTER TABLE `rico16_conversations`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `conversations_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  ADD KEY `conversations_lead_id_foreign` (`lead_id`);
```

**I am not sure if `INDEX` is required to make this right, and on which field i should use it. I have already tried google all over, but not able to find it.**

Here is the query i am using:

```
Lead::where(function($query) use($loginuser){
                        $loginuser->roles[0]->name == 'administrator' ? $query->where('user_id', '!=', 'NULL') : $query->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
                     })
                     ->where('active', 1)
                     ->with(['services', 'services.showstatus', 'services.showstatus.parent', 'users','conversationdetail'])
                     ->whereHas('services', function($query){
                          $query->where('updated_at','>=', DateTimeHelpers::TodayDateStart())
                                ->where('updated_at','<=', DateTimeHelpers::TodayDateEnd());
                     })
                     ->orderBy('id','desc');
```

Or you can refer to this below query.

```
select * 
from `rico16_leads`  
where (`user_id` != ?)  
  and `active` = ?  
  and exists (select *  
              from `rico16_lead_services` 
              where `rico16_lead_services`.`lead_id` = `rico16_leads`.`id`
                and `updated_at` >= ? and `updated_at` <= ? 
      ) 
order by `id` desc
```

Here is how i tried the `JOIN` query version which i tried and it took nearly more then 3.5 seconds to execute:

```
SELECT *  
FROM `rico16_leads` as rl  
LEFT JOIN rico16_lead_services as rls  
  ON rls.lead_id = rl.id  
WHERE user_id != '' AND rl.active = '1'  
  and rls.updated_at >= '2016-07-27 00:00:00'  
  and rls.updated_at < '2016-08-02 23:59:59'  
ORDER BY rl.id DESC
```

Thank you (in advance)!

Comment: And where is the select query that takes so long?

Comment: I am using eloquent query here. So i forgot to post. Let me just post it.

Comment: 1/2 MB download for pictures. Great.

Comment: Can you ditch the pictures? They're enormous and convey almost zero information.

Comment: @Drew Your Internet service provider just made a whole nickel off you. (and me). Give or take :p

Comment: 700K . I was wrong

Comment: I am sorry friends, i just removed all the images.

Comment: @juergend here i have attached the query as well

Comment: I don't know elequent very well, but I feel like this nested where clause might be creating a two-level deep correlated subquery where the relationships of the tables should be expressed in a join instead. That's a total guess though. I would love to see the SQL it produces.

Comment: here is the sql @JNevill   `select * from `rico16_leads` where (`user_id` != ?) and `active` = ? and exists (select * from `rico16_lead_services` where `rico16_lead_services`.`lead_id` = `rico16_leads`.`id` and `updated_at` >= ? and `updated_at` <= ?) order by `id` desc`

Comment: Also i just mentioned along with the description.

Comment: Awesomesauce! Thanks @op.

Comment: Do you think is there any problem that i dont have any `INDEX` here? Do i need to specify that as well?

Comment: Do you have an indexes on these tables? You could probably get a good kick from indexing `rico16_lead_services.lead_id`  and `rico16_leads.id`.

Comment: Ok great. I have also placed a Join Statement as well. On the same query. Which i executed and took about 3.5 seconds to execute.

Comment: No i didnt use any `index` yet on these two. So let me try that as well! @JNevill

Comment: Is there any query you would like to suggest on the same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118934/discussion-between-user3201500-and-jnevill).

Comment: Did you try to run `explain` on query?  As well as you probably want to index: `rls.updated_at`, `rl.active`, `rl.user_id`.

Comment: Woohoooo.....Thanks....@E_p now my join query is taking only 0.009 seconds. Which is really really amazing. :) 

Just one more questions, can i add index to multiple values in a table as well?

Comment: you can have table default collation and not make your create table so unreadable

Comment: Indexes are added on column(s) and can have a `unique` constraint or not. Indexes are not added as you say --> `can i add index to multiple values`

Comment: Sorry for the wrong question. I meant can i make multiple columns as a part of index? obviously that can be provided to a value. :) Is there harm of applying index to more then a certain limit of columns?